# ADF pipeline to load different files(CSV,EXCEL) into Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

[image]I am pretty new to Azure ADF. I have given a task that I need to build a pipeline that takes the different files types like `.csv` and Excel and loaded into Azure SQL.

These source and sync connections coming from control table.

Any help or idea would be appreciated.

I tried using meta driven copy task.. it's working only one type of file system.. not working for Excel

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-data-tool-metadata-driven#known-limitations),

> file format type cannot be parameterized in ADF.

So, you cannot copy multiple types of files through metadata-driven copy data tool.

Alternatively, if you have only `.xlsx` and `.csv` file formats in your file system, you can follow the procedure below:

1. Use the Get Metadata activity to get a list of the files in a directory. Select the required directory in the dataset and create a `Child items` field list. It will get all files in the directory as shown below:

   [image: Get Metadata Activity]
2. Add a ForEach activity to the metadata activity with the `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` expression with Enabled `sequential`. Add an If activity inside the ForEach with the `@contains(item().name,'.xlsx')` condition. Add an Execute Pipeline activity in the true case. Add the pipeline which will take every sheet in the Excel file dynamically to the Azure SQL database.

   The pipeline will have the following activity to select Excel sheets dynamically:

   - Add three variables named `c1` with default value 0, `tempc`, and `iserror` as shown below:

     [image: Variables in Pipeline]
   - Add an Until activity to the pipeline and set variable activity with variable `tempc` with the `@string(add(int(variables('c1')),1))` dynamic expression.
   - Add a Copy activity to the set variable. Select an Excel dataset with `index` and a dynamic value `@int(variables('c1'))`, and `fileName` with a dynamic value `@pipeline().parameters.fileName` parameters as source, and an SQL dataset with `tableName` and a dynamic value `excel@{variables('c1')}` parameter as sink.
   - On success of copy data, add a Set Variable activity with `c1` variable and dynamic value `@variables('tempc')`. On failure of copy data activity, add a Set Variable activity with `iserror` and dynamic value `@bool(1)`. Add `@variables('iserror')` to the Until activity.

   Here is the pipeline JSON of the dynamic Excel sheets copy:

   ```
   {
    "name": "excel",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Until1",
                "type": "Until",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@variables('iserror')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "tempc",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "tempc",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@string(add(int(variables('c1')),1))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "tempc",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "ExcelSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                                    "tableOption": "autoCreate",
                                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Excel1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "index": {
                                            "value": "@int(variables('c1'))",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "fileName": {
                                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.fileName",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "tableName": {
                                            "value": "excel@{variables('c1')}",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "c1",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Copy data1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "c1",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('tempc')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "iserror",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Copy data1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Failed"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "iserror",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@bool(1)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00"
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "fileName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "c1": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "0"
            },
            "iserror": {
                "type": "Boolean"
            },
            "tempc": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2024-02-23T08:00:17Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
    }
   ```
3. Add `@item().name` expression to the `fileName` parameter.
4. Add a Copy Data activity in the false case. Select a delimited text dataset with the parameter `fileName` and dynamic value `@item().name` as source, and an SQL DB dataset with `tableName` parameter and dynamic value `@replace(item().name,'.csv','')` as sink. Debug the pipeline; it will copy all the CSV files and Excel sheets into the SQL database successfully as shown below:

   [image: Debug Pipeline]
5. Run the below script to show the tables which are copied:

   ```
   SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_TYPE =  'BASE TABLE'  and TABLE_SCHEMA =  'dbo'
   ```

   The script will show the tables as shown below:

   | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME |
   | --- | --- |
   | dbo | excel0 |
   | dbo | excel11 |
   | dbo | input |
   | dbo | input1 |

   Here is the pipeline JSON:

   ```
   {
        "name": "pipeline1",
        "properties": {
            "activities": [
                {
                    "name": "Get Metadata1",
                    "type": "GetMetadata",
                    "dependsOn": [],
                    "policy": {
                        "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                        "retry": 0,
                        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                        "secureOutput": false,
                        "secureInput": false
                    },
                    "userProperties": [],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "dataset": {
                            "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                            "type": "DatasetReference"
                        },
                        "fieldList": [
                            "childItems"
                        ],
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "ForEach1",
                    "type": "ForEach",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        {
                            "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                            "dependencyConditions": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "userProperties": [],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "items": {
                            "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "isSequential": true,
                        "activities": [
                            {
                                "name": "If Condition1",
                                "type": "IfCondition",
                                "dependsOn": [],
                                "userProperties": [],
                                "typeProperties": {
                                    "expression": {
                                        "value": "@contains(item().name,'.xlsx')",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "ifFalseActivities": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "Copy data1",
                                            "type": "Copy",
                                            "dependsOn": [],
                                            "policy": {
                                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                                "retry": 0,
                                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                                "secureOutput": false,
                                                "secureInput": false
                                            },
                                            "userProperties": [],
                                            "typeProperties": {
                                                "source": {
                                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                                    "storeSettings": {
                                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                                        "recursive": true,
                                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                                    },
                                                    "formatSettings": {
                                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "sink": {
                                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                                                    "tableOption": "autoCreate",
                                                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                                                },
                                                "enableStaging": false,
                                                "translator": {
                                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "inputs": [
                                                {
                                                    "referenceName": "source",
                                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                                    "parameters": {
                                                        "fileName": {
                                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                                            "type": "Expression"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "outputs": [
                                                {
                                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable2",
                                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                                    "parameters": {
                                                        "tableName": {
                                                            "value": "@replace(item().name,'.csv','')",
                                                            "type": "Expression"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                                            "dependsOn": [],
                                            "policy": {
                                                "secureInput": false
                                            },
                                            "userProperties": [],
                                            "typeProperties": {
                                                "pipeline": {
                                                    "referenceName": "excel",
                                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                                },
                                                "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                                "parameters": {
                                                    "fileName": {
                                                        "value": "@item().name",
                                                        "type": "Expression"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "annotations": [],
            "lastPublishTime": "2024-02-23T08:03:18Z"
        },
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
    }
   ```